# Add "don't use tabs" to the Editing Help page

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I've seen quite a few posts that have bad code formatting because of using tabs.

Right now, only the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page has a note that says: **don't use tabs**. Why not add it to the [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) page as well? After all, the Editing Help page is the most likely place a user looks for help when having formatting problems, because there is a link to it when asking a new question.

Comment: Personally I'm surprised that phrasing hasn't sparked more tabs-vs-spaces flame wars here yet.

Comment: Why? Tabs work fine.

Comment: [Here's the a post on formatting sandbox.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231644/237813)

Comment: @bjb568 They don't work inline (if you're typing in the answer/question box), correct? Or maybe it's just because I'm on a PC... :P

Comment: No, they don't work inline, but you aren't supposed to edit code inline. Copy-paste it.

Comment: On the `python` tag, at least, tabs are tantamount to kicking a puppy.

Comment: @bjb568 The problem with copy-pasted code is that SO's tab stops are often different from the poster's editor. SO uses 8-column tabs, many programmers use 4-column tabs, so things don't line up correctly.

Comment: @Barmar Unless spaces and tabs are mixed, that shouldn't be a problem. It can be fixed with CSS `tab-size: 4`.

Comment: The problem is that spaces and tabs often ARE mixed. I have to fix these things up all the time. They usually have other bad indentation, so I just copy it all to Emacs, re-indent it (with no tabs), and paste it back.